# Get magento shipping amount from each ordered item

Tags: shipping, programmatically, items

I am trying to get shipping and handling amount. I tried the below snippet code but its not working.

```
echo $item->getShippingAmount();
```

but if i try with

```
echo $order->getShippingAmount();
```

It works but that shows total of shipping amount of all order but i want to show for each item.

`item ordered * quantity`

can any one tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

**you can try below code :**

```
foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) 
{
    $output .= "<p>";
    $output .= $item->getWeight();
    $output .= "<br/>";
    $output .= $item->getName() . "<br><span class='subqtyy'>";
    $output .= "QTY:" . $item->getQty() . " | $" .
                    number_format($item->getPrice(), 2);
    $output .= "</span><br></p>";

    $temp_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setCurrentStore(1)
                    ->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
    $quote2 = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');

    //$quote2->setDestPostcode($session->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
        ->getPostcode());
    //$quote2->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('US'); 
    $quote2->setShippingAddress($session->getQuote()
        ->getShippingAddress());
    $temp_product->getStockItem()->setUseConfigManageStock(false);
    $temp_product->getStockItem()->setManageStock(false);

    $quote2->addProduct($temp_product);
    $quote2->setPackageWeight($item->getWeight());

    $quote2->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote2->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
    $rates = $quote2->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();
    //$rates = $quote2->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();

    //var_export($rates);
    foreach ($rates as $rate) {
        $output .= " rbanh = ".$rate->getPrice()." " . $rate->getCode() . " END <br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting other ordered item details using bellow code $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order);
 
$items = $order->getAllItems(); foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
so how ca n mearge with your answer.

Comment: all code here http://pastebin.com/yhNCmHwN

Comment: did above codes work for you ??

Comment: its working but in that code i am not able to get item->shippingamount

Comment: It should be $item->getShippingAmount();

Comment: that i was tried i have mentioned in question.

Comment: its printing shipping amount but if i have two different product in cart its showing shipping amount for first product only